# How To: Have 2 seperate buttons to close modal pop up?

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog, popup

I have a basic modal pop up from w3 schools https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal, and I want to use two links to close the modal, but when I try, nothing works, because both links that I add to close the modal stop working when I try to have 2 links to close the modal

Here is the link that closes the modal 
  `<a href="#" class="close"></a>`

Here is the javascript

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

How can I add this button with class "close"

`<a href="#" class="close"></a>`

And also!! this button with class "close-2"

`<span class="close-2"></span>`

so I can have 2 buttons to close the modal, any help would be great appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly what you would do is set both close buttons as having the same class, so `class="close"`.

Also use a single function for closing the modal dialog such as

```
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Then replace the following

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

with

```
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let closeBtn of spans) {
  closeBtn.onclick = closeModal;
}
```

The reason one of close buttons ceases to work is because `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which represents a collection of found elements. Also the `getElementsByClassName("close")[0]` call returns the first element in the collection and as such only one close button receives the `onclick` event. To fix this, the solution is to not get only the first element but all of the elements then iterate through all of them and add the `onclick` handler to all the elements as demonstrated.

The `class` attribute unlike the `id` attribute does not have to be unique and as such both can have the same `close` value.

Complete working example:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
     <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
function closeModal() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let closeBtn of spans) {
  closeBtn.onclick = closeModal;
}



// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is this right? It is not not working.`// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
for (let closeBtn of spans) {
  closeBtn.onclick = closeModal;
}
  
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}`

Comment: Can you provide a woerkin example please?

Comment: Working example provided, Sorry I forgot to add it. I tested it in the same w3schools example you provided in the original question.

Comment: You are really helping me out, thank you so much, but there is the problem, I need to style the close links two seperate ways, and that is why I needed two different close classes, can we have close, and close-1? How do I assign a different class to each close link, also 1 link shows at all time now but both should be hidden until modal opens up.

Comment: Are both buttons the same html element?

Comment: 1 close link is in the main menu, next to the open link, and 1 close link appears in the modal, is there a way to hide both links until modal is open?

Comment: You can have multiple class names within the `class` attribute. if you so desire you can have a common styling within the `close` style and then specific styles after that by using `class="close close-menu"` for one and `class="close close-modal"` for the other. Or you could simply not define the common close style and still use the `class="close close-menu"` and `class="close close-modal"`. As long as whatever is specified in the `getElementsByClassName()` function is also specified in the element `class` attribute it will work.

Comment: that is brilliant man, but how  can I hide the close links until modal is open, otherwise it is kind of pointless to have the close links showing at at times?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206237/discussion-between-bja-and-chaz-steiner).

Comment: Man, I am struggling, can you show me the javascript as it would be working  with the first solution, because, when I added the necessary parts, it just stopped working. Also, what is your speciality in coding, thank you for the help

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't like extended discussions in comments, but we can talk in the chat link above [also here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206237/discussion-between-bja-and-chaz-steiner).

Comment: I cant seem to find any area to comment in the room, when I click reply to comment, nothing happens, there is no comment reply box in the room,

Comment: Copied from the discussion:
The close link in the dialog will appear and disappear with the dialog, As for the other link I would either add an `Id` attribute to the menu link and show and hide it inside the same functions that show and hide the modal dialog.
You could use `var menuCloseBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn")` and `<a href="#" id="menuBtn">Menu Close Btn</a>` and inside of the `CloseModal` function add `menuCloseBtn.style.display = "none";`

Comment: And when showing the dialog with `modal.style.display = "block"`; use I think  `menuCloseBtn.style.display = "initial"`; (Replace initial with something else if you know css better than I do).

Comment: My specialty in coding is all self taught, but I started in PHP with html and javascript (personal projects), but I don't really know html or css that well. I then progressed onto using C and C++ with the occasional C#. I primarily use C++.

Comment: Sorry I can't help any further for now. it is bed time for me, If you require further assistance I would advice you to ask another question. If there is anything else I can help you with I would be happy to do so when I wake up.

If my answer helped you would you be so kind as to accept my answer [by following this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I was hoping you could just give me the working javascript with the added close button compoments for hiding the button, but in all regards, you are awesome, thank you. Because when I add them it does not work. Have a nie night

Comment: marked as best answer because everything you said was on point, and I got it working, thank you!